# Add kernel-headers to yocto raspberrypi-image

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto-project

How do I add kernel-headers to the yocto image.
I tried adding the below variable in local.conf

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " kernel-dev kernel-devsrc kernel-modules"
```

But I am still unable to see build directory in `/lib/modules/4.19.58/`

Edit 1: I am using meta-raspberrypi-warrior, meta-openembedded-warrior, qt5-warrior 
Edit 2: qt5-image.bb https://pastebin.com/PktdU77F
qt5-basic-image.bb https://pastebin.com/CsML42hk
console-image.bb https://pastebin.com/FKfUiKVE

Comment: Could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The recipe `kernel-dev` is very very BSP-dependant so one can't answer to this question without knowing what BSP you're using in which version.

Nevertheless, to dig further, you can have a look, after a successful build, to `${BUILDDIR}/tmp/deploy/<package type>/kernel-dev.<package type>` to see what is held by `kernel-dev` package.

For example, on my Yocto tree with my "very specific" BSP, the content of `kernel-dev` package is the following:

```
./boot/
./boot/Module.symvers-3.14.29
./boot/System.map-3.14.29
./boot/config-3.14.29
```

To make this recipe install the /usr/src/linux tree, you may implement in your own yocto `meta` a `bbappend` file that will implement a `do_install_append()` function to deploy the required headers.

Comment: I am seeing the same files in my kernel-dev package

Comment: What yocto recipe is used to generate the kernel ? Can you paste or link it ?

Comment: add added the recipe files